# C# instantiate generic type from method signature

Tags: c#, generics

I've been fooling around with generic methods lately and came across methods that look like this:

```
public static void Requires<TException>(bool condition, string message) where TException : Exception
```

To my understanding, when using the above method you provide a `Type` that inherits from `Exception` and if the `condition` is `false` the provided `Exception` type is thrown.

How does this work under the hood?
Is the `TException` instantiated like so `throw new TException();`?
And how can you pass in the `message` parameter if the `Type` is unknown to the method (all it knows is that it inherits type `Exception`)?

Comment: Is this Code Contracts code? In this case `Requires` means more than simply checking a condition and throwing an exception

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I saw it in Code Contracts yes. I'm not so much interested in what it does, I'm more interested in how one would take the generic type, create a new instance of it, and then use it.

Comment: If the method has the `where T:new` constraint, you simply call `new T()`. Code Contracts methods probably have this constraint as well, or use specialized versions for eg. argument exceptions. The source code is [available in Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MSDN : [System.Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) does have constructor that takes a string as argument. This string represents the message.

With the help of the [Activator-Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wccyzw83(v=VS.110).aspx) you can do the following pretty simple:

```
 using System;

public class Test
{

   public static void Requires<TException>(bool condition, string message) 
where TException : Exception
{
    Exception exception = (Exception)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TException),message);
    throw exception;
}

  public static void Main()
  {
      try
      {
          Requires<ArgumentNullException>(true,"Test");
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(e);
      }

   }
}
```

Working example:
http://ideone.com/BeHYUO

Answer (score 2):

> To my understanding, when using the above method you provide a Type that inherits from Exception and if the condition is false the provided Exception type is thrown.

That depends on the implementation of the method, all it is saying is that the type parameter of the `Requires` method must have a base type of `Exception`. But it is highly likely that it creates an exception of that type if the condition is `false`. One way to do that is with `Activator.CreateInstance` method.

Comment: Sure, I'm with you so far. But what if I needed to make a new instance of that `Type` in a method I make myself?

Comment: If the type has the `new` constraint, you can simply call `new TException()`

Comment: You can use `default(Type)` or if you have a `new()` constraint you can use `new Type()`.

Answer (score 1):

> And how can you pass in the message parameter if the Type is unknown
>   to the method

Similarly to **Ned Stoyanov**'s answer, it's up to the person implementing the method to decide how this parameter will be used. It can be used as a message imbedded in the exception, it can be used somewhere else or it can be not used at all. The parameter name only suggests what it will be used for, but the caller has no guarantee that it will be used as he expects. It could be called `djfhsfjfh` as well .